# How to display join result in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to join three tables using inner join and i did as follows

```
@posts = SubCategory.joins(products: :posts)
```

Now I am trying to list the fields for `posts` table but it is throwing error as

```
undefined method `title' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Post:0x9932f84>
```

i tried something like this i my view but it doen't help

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h4><%= post.posts.title %></h4>
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions

**Edit 1**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Posts#index

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column posts.sub_category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."sub_category_i...
```

It is true i don't have sub_category_id in my posts table. But i have product_id in my posts table.

Comment: use includes instead of join. if you use join then you don't get the associated model record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read your query it says to me *"Give me all of the SubCategories that have a product with a post"*. And the call to `.posts` on your `|post|` (which really is a subcategory) shows that you have defined a collection `posts`. So there must be more than one Post per SubCategory.

Since `post.posts` is a collection then you probably need to iterate over it.

```
<% post.posts.each do |p| %>
  <h4><%= p.title %></h4>
<% end %>
```

It would be useful to see the code for `sub_category.rb`

**Another thought**

In case you really just want to get every post even if sub_categories and products are repeated then just do this:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:product => :sub_category)
```

Then you'll always get Post instances and you can do this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h4><%= post.title %></h4>
<% end %>
```

Rails may not always do a join here though. Either way it tries to pull product and sub_category in one shot.

**If you just want Post data with no other fields but you want a join. Do this:**

```
@posts = Post.joins(:product => :sub_category)
```

This should produce a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
     INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "posts"."product_id" 
     INNER JOIN "sub_categories" ON "sub_categories"."id" = "products"."sub_category_id"
```

Comment: agreed.  @tyler is correct that you can use a map, but then you'll still have an array with a bunch of titles, and the goal seems to indicate otherwise

Comment: I am just checking with product and sub category key and getting my post data i don't want to display any other fields. I just need posts table data alone. Any other way

Comment: Just updated the answer to give post data alone as long as there's a valid product and sub_category. This is guessing without knowing which fields are in your tables though.

Comment: It is working with minimum records. Ill check with bunch records. However can you post a raw query for your latest query just for my understanding

Comment: Added what the query should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The `.title` method is for each individual post.  If you want an array of titles for the array of posts, you can do something like:

```
<%= post.posts.map(&:title) %>
```

If you simply want the title for each post, you can do:

```
<%= post.title %>
```